# JQuery conflict between .hide() and .onclick()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, dom

So I'm developing a script that makes use of a dropdown (class typeahead_list) and a textbox (class et_email) in Bootstrap. Whenever the text box loses focus, I need the dropdown to close. But if someone clicks on one of the list items in the dropdown (class et_li), the contents of that list item must populate the text box before closing the dropdown.

Note: All of the **lis** are dynamically generated. I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

This code puts the **li** contents into the textbox, but does not close the dropdown.

```
$( ".et_email" ).focusout(function() {
    $(".typeahead_list").on("click", "li", function() {
        $(".et_email").val($(this).text());});  
    //$(".typeahead_list").hide();
});
```

This code closes the dropdown, but does not put the contents of the **li** into the text box.

```
$( ".et_email" ).focusout(function() {
    $(".typeahead_list").on("click", "li", function() {
        $(".et_email").val($(this).text());});  
    $(".typeahead_list").hide();
});
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Where is the conflict coming from?

**UPDATE:**

Alex Cassady suggested the following fix:

```
$(".typeahead_list").on("click", "li", function() {
    $(".et_email").val($(this).text()); // copy value
    $(".typeahead_list").hide(); // then hide
});
```

Thank you for your help. I've looked into a solution similar to this before. However, I was having an issue because I need the dropdown to close whenever the email box loses focus for any reason at all... while still responding to the li click. With this example, the dropdown only closes when someone clicks on the li.

But if I try to add another handler for $( ".et_email" ).focusout() within the $(document).ready(), it completely invalidates the effects of this function. It's like $( ".et_email" ).focusout() and $(".typeahead_list").on("click", "li", function(){}) can't live in the same universe together. There is some kind of conflict.

Basically, the rule I need to implement is: Always close the dropdown when et_email loses focus for any reason... but if focus is lost because of an li click with the typeahead_list div, then populate the text box with the contents of that li before closing the dropdown.

Comment: No errors in console? is this function inside a `$(document).ready` function?

Comment: Don't nest handlers...

Comment: @odedta - yes, it's in the $(document).ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding a click listener to an element which will be hidden right away and so can not be clicked! The reason it works if you comment the `hide()` line is because it can be clicked.

If you just want the text before hiding:

```
$( ".et_email" ).focusout(function() {
    $(".et_email").val($(".typeahead_list").text());  
    $(".typeahead_list").hide();
});
```

**EDIT:**

Alright I think I have a better understanding of what you're trying to do. This is not a clean solution, but will do the job.

Have a global variable 'focusLost' or anything, It'll be set to true every time `.et_email` loses focus and set to false in a second. In `.typeahead_list` click listener we check whether focusLost is true.

```
var focusLost = false;

$('.typeahead_list').on('click', function () {
    if (focusLost) {
        $('.et_email').val(($(this).text()));
        $(this).hide();
    }
});

$('.et_email').focusout(function () {
    focusLost = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.typeahead_list').hide();
        focusLost = false;
    }, 1000);
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/08xvcst5/1/)

Comment: Thanks Samurai. Unfortunately, this populates the textbox with the contents of typeahead_list whenever et_email loses focus. This should only happen when focus is lost as the result of clicking one of the li elements within typeahead_list. All other causes losing focus should simply close the dropdown without altering the contents of the textbox.

Comment: See the edit, also added a demo, wasn't too sure about the dropdown, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

As A. Wolff said, don't nest handlers. The focusout event is binded to all .et_email, but the click event isn't binded to the .typeahead_list until the focusout event is triggered.

The .typeahead_list is being hidden before the value can be changed. Focusout is the same as clicking outside of .et_email and it's being called first.
Removing the focusout event handler completely should solve the problem.

```
$(".typeahead_list").on("click", "li", function() {
    $(".et_email").val($(this).text()); // copy value
    $(".typeahead_list").hide(); // then hide
});
```

Edit: You could also try copying the value in a callback function for $.hide()

```
$(".typeahead_list").on("click", "li", function() {

    $(".typeahead_list").hide( function() {
        $(".et_email").val($(this).text()); // copy value
    }); // then hide
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've looked into a solution similar to this before. However, I was having an issue because I need the dropdown to close whenever the email box loses focus for any reason at all... while still responding to the li click. With this example, the dropdown only closes when someone clicks on the li. See details in my update above.